# Apollonian gasket

Tags: circles, systems-of-equations, osculating-circle

Okay , is there a way to find the radius of the nth circle in a apollonian gasket ..

Something like this

[image]

Its like simple case of apollonian gasket ..

I found from descartes' theorem

$R_n = 2\cdot\sqrt{ R_{n-1}\cdot R_1 + R_n-1\cdot R_2 + R_1\cdot R_2} +R_{n-1} + R_1 +R_2 $

I have the values of $R_1,R_2,R_3,R_4$ ..

where $R_n$ is the curvature and not the radius
So I have this question

1. Is there anywhere this will fail ?
2. Can it be more simplified to get $R_n$ in terms $n$
3. Is there any faster way to calculate for large numbers as $n=10^8$

Comment: What's the $n^{\text{th}}$ circle? Keep in mind that, given three mutually tangent circles, we expect *two* more circles mutually tangent to all three. Not just one.  So your $C_4$ is not uniquely determined.

Comment: Look at the diagram .. @MarkMcClure , thats how the cirlces are formed .. Its like a small part of apollonian gasket ... SO I have $C_1 , C_2 , C_3 $ as given in the diagram and I need to find the radius of $C_4 , C_5 $ and so on .. The $nth$ circle is the nth circle in the diagram  i.e the one surrounded by $C_1 , C_2 $ and $ C_{n-1}  $

Comment: I still don't see how your $C_4$ is well defined. If I understand your question correctly, though, then a somewhat simpler but still recursive formula for the *curvatures* $\kappa_n=1/r_n$ might be: $\kappa_n = 2 (\kappa_1 + \kappa_2 + \kappa_{n-1}) - \kappa_{n-2}$.

Comment: Okay @MarkMcClure , if I say $C_4$ is also given ...  does it make it any better for you and Ya I have edited the question a bit $R_n$ being the curvature and $R_4$ as given and ya yourr generalisation is perfect ... thanks .. it helps a bit

Comment: Can you generalise it a bit more like maybe i can skip calculating 10-20 at a time .. or something like that

Comment: Essentially from the Code Chef July Challenge 2015 ([Rohith and Circles problem](http://www.codechef.com/JULY15/problems/NTHCIR)), ending on 13 July 2015 at 15:00 IST (09:30 UTC). Question will remain locked until after this time, at which point already submitted answers will be undeleted.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, there is a way.

To simplify the formula, I will relabel your circles as follows.

- Let $S_a$ and $S_b$ be your circle $C_1$ and $C_2$.
- Let $S_0, S_1, S_2, \ldots$ be your circle $C_3, C_4, C_5, \ldots$.
- Given $C_1, C_2, C_3$, there are two possible configurations of $C_4$.
  Let $S_{-1}$ be the other possible configuration of $C_4$ differ from $S_{1}$.

Let $r_n$ be the radius of circle $S_n$ where $n = a, b$ or $\ge -1$ and $\rho_n = \frac{1}{r_n}$.

Recall $S_a$ is the outer circle. If we apply [Descartes circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_theorem) to
circles $S_a, S_b, S_{n}, S_{n\pm 1}$ for $n \ge 0$, we have

$$ 2( \rho_a^2 + \rho_b^2 + \rho_n^2 + \rho_{n\pm 1}^2 ) = (-\rho_a + \rho_b + \rho_n + \rho_{n\pm 1})^2$$

So $\rho_{n\pm 1}$ are the two roots of a quadratic equation.

$$\rho^2 - 2(-\rho_a + \rho_b + \rho_n ) \rho + 
\left(2(\rho_a^2 + \rho_b^2 + \rho_n^2 ) - (-\rho_a + \rho_b + \rho_n)^2\right) = 0\tag{*1}$$
This implies
$$\rho_{n+1}-2\rho_n + \rho_{n-1} = 2A
\quad\text{ where }\quad A = \rho_b - \rho_a = \frac{1}{r_b} - \frac{1}{r_a}$$

This is a linear recurrence relation in $\rho_n$ and its general solution has the
form
$$\rho_{n} = A n^2 + B n  + C$$
In particular, we have
$$\begin{cases}
\rho_1    &= A + B + C\\
\rho_0    &= C\\
\rho_{-1} &= A - B + C\\
\end{cases}
\implies 
\begin{cases}
B &= \frac12\left( \rho_1 - \rho_{-1} \right)\\
C &= \rho_0
\end{cases}$$
This leads to

$$\rho_n = (\rho_b - \rho_a) n^2 + \frac12 (\rho_1 - \rho_{-1}) n + \rho_0$$

You can obtain the values of $\rho_{\pm 1}$ by solving the quadratic equation
$(*1)$ for $n = 0$. To match your diagram, $\rho_1$ should be the smaller one of the two roots.

Comment: We'll reopen this later --- Good answer